# Keep getting "bad addressing" when calling read()

Tags: c, calloc

I'm doing a client-server in C and I keep getting a bad address.
I think the problem is with the second argument of read(), here is the code:

Function definition:

```
int send_modbus_request(char *server_add, unsigned int port, uint8_t *APDU, uint16_t APDUlen, uint8_t *APDU_R);
```

Read call that returns an error:

```
//receive response MBAPDU payload (APDU_R) - get size from "Length" field
int len = (MBAPDU_R[4]<<8) + MBAPDU_R[5];   //recover the "length" field from [4][5]

if (read(new_socket, APDU_R, len-1)<0) {
    printf("[TCP] Error: reading APDU_R from socket\n");
    printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}
```

APDU_R memory allocation :

```
uint8_t *APDU_R = (uint8_t *)calloc(ADPURLENW, sizeof(uint8_t));
```

Comment: What is `ADPURLENW`? What is `MBAPDU_R`? What will be the value of `len`?

Comment: Do you test whether the `calloc()` call succeeds?  Overall, the code presented is not complete or coherent enough for us to troubleshoot.  Our standard expectation is that debugging requests be based on a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.  Please present one.

Comment: "Bad address" (`EFAULT`) means that the `APDU_R` pointer did not point to valid memory.  Either `calloc` failed, or the pointer got corrupted in between, or (on some systems) the amount of space allocated was less than `len-1`.